# How to force Common Lisp to treat numerals as symbol names?

Tags: common-lisp, reader-macro

I hope these codes

```
(12 3.5 1e4)
```

could be treated as three symbols

```
(|12| |3.5| |1e4|)
```

rather than three numbers.

Can I fulfill this by setting the reader?

---

**Update:**

I have a collection of data which is organized as nested lists:

```
(abc,d/e-f    12ab, 21e4, %rqa, (foo bar), ....)
```

Different items are separated by **commas or spaces (tab and newline included)**. I want to read them in w.r.t. the nested structure, and without changing any character. The commas can be set as spaces by this:

```
(set-syntax-from-char #\, #\Space)
```

Finally the problem remains at the numbers. `21e4` is transferred to `210000.0` by the reader. I don't want to write a parser all from scratch, and try to utilize the reader of common-lisp as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Example for `1`, works in LispWorks:

```
CL-USER 1 > (setf rt0 *readtable*)
#<READTABLE 40F0038923>

CL-USER 2 > (setf rt1 (copy-readtable nil))
#<READTABLE 4020008C23>

CL-USER 3 > (defun read-digit-symbol (stream char)
              (let ((*readtable* rt0))
                (unread-char char stream)
                (intern
                  (princ-to-string
                    (read stream t nil t)))))
READ-DIGIT-SYMBOL

CL-USER 4 > (set-macro-character #\1 #'read-digit-symbol t rt1)
T

CL-USER 5 > (defun test ()
              (let ((*readtable* rt1))
                (read-from-string "(1 11 111)")))
TEST

CL-USER 6 > (test)
(\1 |11| |111|)
10

CL-USER 7 >
```

Comment: I like it if he can specify that his data doesn't contain ratios, e.g. 111/111 -> |1| in my local sbcl. I would additionally be tempted to bind \*read-base\* and \*print-base\* at some point to ensure that they are in sync during the read and the princ. Even if he binds them to 2 in TEST he will need to set the reader macro for all 10 digits, or else floats will still read as numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer first, but this is not exactly what I want. For example, if the text is `123.000`, the `(intern (princ-to-string ...` will turn it to `|123.0|`, which is not equal to `|123.000|`. In your solution, the texts are first converted to numbers and then converted back to symbol, during this procedure the content may change.

Comment: @SaltyEgg: you may want to edit your question to describe the requirements in more detail...

Comment: @RainerJoswig Sorry for my non-detailed question. I've updated it.

Answer (score 3):

You could, I guess. But that would probably end in tears, as you would lose the ability to read numbers.

What are you trying to accomplish, with this, that isn't solvable by iterating over a list of numbers, creating symbols with `make-symbol` and `string`?

Comment: This is a good response, but should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I just have to process a collection of symbols, and some of them are legal numbers for common lisp. I don't want CL to convert them to numbers.